# Templates - "Unspecialized class template cannot be used as a template"

Tags: c++, templates

```
#pragma once

#include <memory>

template <typename T>
class TreeHeader
{
private:
    unsigned int size;
    std::unique_ptr<Node<T>> root;

public:
    virtual void size_inc();
    virtual void size_dev();
};

template <typename T>
class Node
{
private:
    T data;

protected:
    Node();

public:
    void set_data(const T& val);
    T& get_data();
};
```

Specifically the compiler errors (about 5 from the same line) come from `std::unique_ptr<Node<T>> root;`.

It's not clear to me why this does not work. I've also tried `std::unique_ptr<Node>` but it gives an error and does not make as much sense to me as well.

Comment: Maybe put the definition of `Node` before the `TreeHeader` class? Or at least have a forward declaration of `Node`?

Comment: Well, that's not a great way to get an error. Thanks, if you put it as an answer I'll choose it.